# what is difference between $this->requestElement() and $this->element();

Tags: cakephp, html-helper

i use cakephp and i am beginner 
i use

```
$this->requestElement()
```

in

> default.ctp

file but i face error.
but when use

> $this->element()

my problem solved.
i face question that what is difference between `$this->requestElement()` and `$this->element();`
when i use `requestElement()` and when i use `element()` ?
thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

requestElement is outdated/deprecated (was used prior to 1.3).

you should now use element()

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you've found the method `requestElement()` but I can't find it in the API documentation. If the method ever existed it's likely been deprecated in later versions of Cake.

Or did you mean [`requestAction()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/991/requestAction)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean `renderElement` instead of `requestElement`. `renderElement` was deprecated in CakePHP 1.2, and has been removed in later versions.